# Errors after installing tensorflow in python 3.5 gpu through pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I have installed tensorflow through native pip, then these errors show up. I don't know if this is a problem with python distribution. I have recently encountered a problem when working with ros; anaconda and ros needed different versions,so I have solved somehow by removing the path in anaconda or something:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Comment: What version of CUDA have you installed? And it in PATH?

Comment: @user2781994 I've installed CUDA 9.1. I did't understand what you are asking about PATH.

Comment: Tensorflow is compiled for CUDA 9.0, you need to install 9.0 instead of 9.1 or compile tensorflow from source.

The other question was if libcublas location (that means CUDA libraries) is in your environment variable named PATH. But anyway, first install CUDA 9.0 or compile tensorflow.